# Htaccess manipulation error log and redirect 503 if php has error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my error display.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function test() in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 3 Call Stack: 0.0788 241120 1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\test.php:0
```

But i want like this.

```
[Wed Oct 01 15:07:23 2008] [error] [client 76.246.51.127] Call to undefined function test() in C:\wamp\www\test.php:3
```

How can i do it with .htaccess not php or php.ini file and i want redirect to error/503.php if php have error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't handle it with a .htaccess. Why can't you use PHP for handling that ?
With PHP5.2+ you can catch fatal errors with `register_shutdown_function` :

```
register_shutdown_function('fatal_errors');
function fatal_errors()
{
  // do stuff
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php